# Publishing does not get past "Waiting for Deployment"

Tags: 2011, publishing

I am trying to install Tridion 2011 SP1 and am almost there. My installation is complete and I am trying to publish a sample page to make sure everything gets to the target location. Publishing gets stuck at "Waiting for Deployment" and stays there till maximum attempts are reached. My Java versions are correct and am using the appropriate dlls/jars for 32 bit installation.

Thanks,
Aravind

Comment: Did either of the answers help solve your issue? Please accept one if so, otherwise posting a follow-up answer can help others with a similar issue.

Answer (score 6):

This status means that your publish action has now rendered the templates, it has created a transport package and that package has been transported to the Deployer. Can you confirm you have a `local file system` transport mechanism in your Publication Target? With an HTTP/FTP deployer I think you would get a transport error already.

Next phase in the publish process would be the Deployer picking up your transport package and proceed with deployment. That however seems to not happen. The obvious cause would be that there is no Deployer listening to pick up the transport package.

So, things to check:

- do you have a Deployer running?
- is the Deployer configured to 'listen' to the same `Incoming` folder that you specified in the Publication Target? Check your `cd_deployer_conf.xml`

Comment: FTP and Local file system both work with a straightforward "incoming" directory. More recently (2011+ ??) HTTP deployment works in a very similar way - in the deployer config, you can configure Deployer/Queue/Location/@Path, and  also Deployer/HTTPSReceiver/@Location. These locations need to match. (If I have it right, the https receiver drops the package in the httpsreceiver location, and the deployer picks them up from the queue location.) If they don't match, the transport will succeed, and you'll find the packages waiting unprocessed in the receiver location.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I'd check:

- The configuration of your deployer - can you hit the URL of your http upload application.
- Is this same URL configured in your publication target?
- If these two look ok, are you logging this information?  check the logback.xml file and ensure you can gather some logging as to what's happening.
- Also check the publishing service on the CME side (or dedicated publishing machines if load-balanced) - perhaps these services are not running?

If you happen to get some logging infromation, i'd update your question as i'm sure you'll get the answer here almost immediately :)